# How to get the base form of an adj or adverb using lemma in spacy

Tags: python, spacy, lemmatization

For a project, I would like to be able to get the noun form of an adjective or adverb if there is one using NLP.
For example, "deathly" would return "death" and "dead" would return "death".
"lively" would return "life".

I've tried using the spacy lemmatizer but it does not manage to get the base radical form.
For example, if I'd do:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
z = nlp("deathly lively")
for token in z:
    print(token.lemma_)
```

It would return:
`>>> deathly lively`
instead of:
`>>> death life`

Does anyone have any ideas?
Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen so far, SpaCy is not super-great at doing what you want it to do. Instead, I am using a 3rd party library called [pyinflect](https://pypi.org/project/pyinflect/), which is intended to be used as an extension to SpaCy.

While it isn't perfect, I think it will work better than your current approach.

I'm also considering another 3rd-party library called [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/), which might be worth checking out, as well.